# Discord bot that accepts more than one word as an argument

Tags: python, discord

So, I'm making a bot that is able to warn users. I was wondering if there is a way to make it so that it can accept more than one word in the "reason" parameter, without having to write quotation marks.

```
@client.command(name = "warn")
@commands.has_role("staff")
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason = "No reason given"):
    publiclog = client.get_channel("channel id")
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=":warning: Warning", description=f"{member} has been warned", colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    embedVar.add_field(name="Reason", value= reason, inline=True)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Warned by:", value= f"{ctx.author}", inline=True)
    embedVar.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(f"<@{member.id}> has been warned. Reason: {reason}")
    await publiclog.send(embed=embedVar)
```

So, right now, if a staff member calls the function and they write `>warn @user they were mean`, the bot will only write as a reason "they". Is there a way to make it so that it writes the whole reason, without having to write `>warn @user "they were mean"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = "No reason given"):
```

I think if you will add the `*,` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(name = "warn")
@commands.has_role("staff")
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *reason = "No reason given"):
    reason = " ".join(reason)
    publiclog = client.get_channel("channel id")
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=":warning: Warning", description=f"{member} has been warned", colour = discord.Colour.orange())
    embedVar.add_field(name="Reason", value= reason, inline=True)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Warned by:", value= f"{ctx.author}", inline=True)
    embedVar.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(f"<@{member.id}> has been warned. Reason: {reason}")
    await publiclog.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Adding * will accept any number of arguments for reason and joining them will make it a string

Comment: I understand the reasoning, but when I write the * before reason I get a syntax error.